# Extra space at the bottom of LIs that contain a TABLE on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

View the following code on IE7 (or on later version of Internet Explorer in IE7 mode):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ol, li
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        li
        {
            background: yellow;
        }
        li table
        {
            background: red;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

A space gets added at the bottom of each LI. Any idea why? How can you remove that extra space?

Note: I tried using a DIV with `display:list-item` instead of the LI, and I can also reproduce the problem this way.

Comment: have you tried removing the white space? ie put everything from `<ol>` to `</ol>` on a single line. I know it will make a mess of the formatting, but it's worth a try -- I remember some quirk with old IE in lists where it would render the white space.

Comment: Yes I tried to put everything that's in the OL on a single line, without whitespace. But it does not change anything.

Comment: I have found this link [IE7-/Win — Extra vertical space in Lists](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWlispace.php) which reports the same bug. However, the cause is different there. I checked the `hasLayout` property of my LIs and OL using the developer toolbar, and they are both set to false (0).

Comment: ah well, it was worth a try.

Comment: You could also trying setting line-height: 100% to all `li` elements. Are the any images in the elements that produce additional vertical spacing?

Comment: Tried that too... Still the same few pixels gap at the bottom of the LI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Adrift's answer, setting `vertical-align: bottom` on the LI and `zoom: 1` will do the trick, without the possible side effects of the Adrift's solution.

In fact, I believe that `zoom: 1` can be replaced with any property that gives the LI a layout, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533776.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

IE has a habit of rendering whitespace when it shouldn't. Change instances of this:

```
    </table>
</li>
```

to this:

```
    </table></li>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, even if you write '<ol><li><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table></li><li><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td>test</td></tr></table></li></ol>'